# Unhandled Alert Exception in selenium, c#

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

I am new to Selenium, and I am trying to verify that if user has successfully landed on the Home page or not. Here is the snippet:

```
LoginPage.GoTo();//Goes Well

LoginPage.LoginAs("UserName").WithPassword("Password").Login();//goes Well

Assert.IsTrue(HomePage.IsAt, "Failed to login");//Below is the implementation of HomePAge.IsAt
public static bool IsAt
{     
   get 
     {
     var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
     wait.Until(x => x.SwitchTo().ActiveElement().GetAttribute("id") == "IDHere");//Here the exception is occuring.
     }
     var homePage = Driver().Instance.FindElement(By.Id("IDHere"));
//   return true or False;
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: FYI, when I try to run my application, a window authentication pop up comes and after that Page loads.

Comment: What happens if catch the exception? "Unhandled Exception" is not a Selenium thing, but C# (or other languages') way of telling you that you need to handle a (potential) exception. Using try-catch is a good way to do this. Also, you need to look at the API to find out what this exception is about: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/UnhandledAlertException.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an alert is present on your browser, it prevents you from actually doing ANYTHING else.

> FYI, when I try to run my application, a window authentication pop up
>   comes and after that Page loads.

Well, yeah. That's the **alert** part from "Unhandled **Alert** Exception". The **unhandled** part, is because you didn't use any line of code to show your program how to handle the alert. Selenium goes to login page. Then tries to run this line `x.SwitchTo().ActiveElement().GetAttribute("id") == "IDHere"`, but there is an alert on your page that prevents you from doing anything.

You have to actually try to handle it (close it or accept the message) and **THEN** do anything else.

It might be considered a good practice to wait for your alert to appear (since it might not appear instantly), and then, after (e.g.) 5 seconds, if there is no alert, run your code.

Try the code below to see if it resolves your problem:

```
public static boid WaitForAlert(bool accept)
{
    //Initialize your wait.
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    //Wait for alert
    try
    {
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());    
        if (accept)
        {
            Driver().Instance.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
        }
        else
        {
            Driver().Instance.SwitchTo().Alert().Dismiss();
        }    
    }
    catch (WebDriverTimeoutException) { /*Alert did not appear, do nothing*/ }
}
```

And then do:

```
LoginPage.GoTo();
LoginPage.LoginAs("UserName").WithPassword("Password").Login();
LoginPage.WaitForAlert(true); //True to accept the alert
Assert.IsTrue(HomePage.IsAt, "Failed to login");
```

Comment: Marking as accepted answer. Thanks alot.
BTW, Alert PopUp and Window authentication Popup both need to be handled in this way right?

Comment: @RishiVedpathi if you can, attach a screenshot to know exactly what alert appears. But if it's on your browser, it would basically be the same thing. If it's something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQhAf.png , then yeah, it's a browser alert. The difference is that the simple alert, you can only accept/dismiss it. The authentication alert, you can send credentials. If you have an authentication alert, I believe there are functions in the webDriver that allow you to send username and password to an alert. Try to do Driver().Instance.SwitchTo().Alert(). and see what functions you get.